# how to connect strain gauge to HX711 module

Tags: arduino, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

I need get strain gauge reading to Arduino. so far i have found load cell Wheatstone configuration circuit **[here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199487/connect-hx711-to-a-three-wire-load-cell) 3rd answer**. I need to know if i connect a strain gauge to one **+Active** resistance, and **other 3** resistances left with **350Ohm** constant resistors, will this configuration give me strain gauge reading with same connection as given in the circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know if i connect a strain gauge to one +Active resistance, and other 3 resistances left with 350Ohm constant resistors, will this configuration give me strain gauge reading with same connection as given in the circuit?

You will get 1/2 the full-scale output when using a full bridge design with only 1 active strain gauge, compared to using a full bridge bridge with 2 active gauges.

This is can be acceptable to designers because the benefits of using a full gauge outweigh the costs.  Benefits can include better CMR and less drift due to temperature changes. If your active gauge is remote from the three fixed resistors, then be certain to use a 3-wire connection to the active gauge.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula below:

[image: formula]

You get the answer. R_1, R_2 and R_3 are known values, (R_2 is adjustable for calib. or can be), and R_x is your weightcell.

[image: wheatstone]

Remember that your config. will only be a quarter bridge. You can find additional info on:
http://www.vishaypg.com/docs/11092/tt612.pdf
source: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge

Comment: for the ic hx711 A-->E+, C-->E-, B-->A+, D-->A- right? i will left R1. R2 ,R3 with 350ohm and Rx 350ohm strain gauge

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand