# Total Weight for load cell when connected in a wheat stone pattern?

Tags: circuit-design, load-cell

[image]I have 4 load cells from AnyLoad, Model 563YH-SE5Klb. Each Load cell is 5Klb and i want to connect them in a wheat stone bridge format. My surface area for the load is 3 feet by 5 feet, and thats why i have to use a wheat stone design.
How much is the total pound capacity while using these load cell in the wheat stone pattern? How does one do its calculation?

Please refer the picture below for the specification of the quadro set that i have.

Comment: the limited info on them reads like they are already internally wheatstone connected. Perhaps you'd link to the electrical connections for them to clarify this. Are you asking how to add their outputs together?

Comment: You would normally be using a wheatstone bridge configuration to connect 4 individual strain gauges to make a single load-cell. Connecting 4 load-cells in a wheatstone bridge isn't really possible.

Comment: @Neil_UK
I have attached the picture above of the quadro set that i have. It has 4 load cell to be installed on 4 corners of the unit. My load is 7-10Klbs and each of these loads cells in the picture is 5klbs.

Comment: If you use them as half bridges you can connect them up as per [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174560/how-to-set-up-load-sensor-in-a-full-bridge-with-amplifier)

Comment: Isnt this a full bridge.
alright so if i connect it this way, my question is, what would be the total weight capacity of the load cells when connected under a half/full bridge?
So as i understand, using 4-5Klbs loads cell would give me a total of 10Klbs if connected under a full bridge. right?

Comment: With 4x 5klb cells, you ought to be able to weigh up to 20klbs for a symmetrically placed load, and up to 5klbs for a maximally eccentric load. The electrical interconnection will depend on the circuit diagram of the load cells. I don't see your link to the electrical information yet, pretty though the picture of the 4 load cells is.

Comment: @Neil_UK
Here is the link on the load cell: http://www.anyload.com/en/product/563yh-single-ended-beam-load-cell/
Thanks

Comment: I said electrical data, not mechanical. Find the electrical data, wire colours, wire functions, schematic of what's in the cell, how it should be connected to an amplifier. Even a description of whether it's half or full bridge would be better than the nothing we have now.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously a full bridge sensor (4 wire) since as part of the [datasheet](http://www.anyload.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Anyload-563YH-load-cell-transducer.pdf) it has the Zero balance for the bridge specified. If it was a half bridge it would only have 3 wires and would not specify a balance accuracy.

[image]

[image]

As a full bridge, you need to connect each sensor to an amp, you cannot connect 4 sensors into a single bridge configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So with 4 sensors, i can get 20Klbs ? all in a full bridge style?